# Is there a method like "ILIKE" I can use in a Rails conditional statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to perform an action if a string is contained, non-case-sensitively, in another string.

So my if statement would look something like this:

```
@a = "search"
if @a ILIKE "fullSearch"
  #do stuff
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. We'd like to know where you searched, and what you tried. There are multiple ways to get to what you want, but we don't want to repeat your attempts and find out they don't meet your needs. This is covered in tutorials for Ruby and the String documentation shows methods you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get there. Here are three:

```
'Foo'.downcase.include?('f') # => true
'Foo'.downcase['f'] # => "f"
```

Those are documented in [the String documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html) which you need to become very familiar with if you're going to program in Ruby.

```
'Foo'[/f/i] # => "F"
```

This is a mix of String's `[]` `slice` shortcut and regular expressions. I'd recommend one of the first two because they're faster, but for thoroughness I added it because people like hitting things with the regex hammer. [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html) contains documentation for `/f/i`.

You'll notice that they return different things. Ruby considers anything other than `false` or `nil` as true, AKA "truthiness", so all three are returning a `true` value, and, as a result you could use them in conditional tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `include?` method. So in this case:

```
@var = 'Search'
if var.include? 'ear'
  #action
end
```

Remember `include?` method is case-sensitive. So if you use something like `include? 'sea'` it would return `false`. You may want to do a `downcase` before calling `include?()`

```
@var = 'Search'
if var.downcase.include? 'sea'
  #action
end
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regexp with `i` option. `i` for insensitive I think.

```
a = "fullSearch"
a =~ /search/i
 => 4 
a =~ /search/
 => nil
```

Or you could downcase your string and check if it's present in the other

```
a = "fullSearch"
a.downcase.include?('search')
 => true
```

Comment: Now explain how regex work and why the OP would want to use them. Good answers should contain more than code to educate not merely answer.